# Implementation of out or ref keyword in typescript 2.8.1

Tags: typescript

Below is my code snippet,

```
 public static TestInfo(input1: string, input2: string, out firstOutput:string) {
   const firstOutput = class1.callingfunctionabc(input1, input2);
   return class2.callingfunctionxyz(firstoutput);
}
```

now here i need both output i.e. firstOutput and output of **class2.callingfunctionxyz(firstoutput)** for further manupulation in my 
code. I don't know how to get both outputs in typescript.

So Is it possible in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function cannot return multiple values. If several variables have to be returned, they should be merged into a single object:

```
public static TestInfo(input1: string, input2: string) {
   const firstOutput: string = class1.callingfunctionabc(input1, input2);
   const secondOutput: string = class2.callingfunctionxyz(firstOutput);
   return { firstOutput, secondOutput };
}
```